# How to find sum of the elements in the Subsets

Tags: java

I want to find the number of subsets whose elements are divisible by 2 or whose sum of the elements is divisible by 2

I have found all the possible subset of the given array

```
for(int i=1;i<=(Math.pow(2,n));i++) //Loop for all 2^n combinations
    {
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((i&(1<<j))>0) //This gives the subset of the array
```

Input:1 2 3
Output: 3 as {2},{1,3=4},{1,2,3=6} are the subsets which are divisible by 2 or whose sum of the elements is divisible by 2.

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=(Math.pow(2,n));i++)` .... *no serious* programmer would do this, because *he* knows **how much** 2^n is/can get....

Comment: even when "the boss" *really wants* it - the answer is: No! First buy a quantum computer!

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumptions, that:

- input is `n` (a natural number)
- output is the count of "even subsets" (in a sequence of natural numbers of size n)

...the (exact) result is:

[image: sum(binomial(n - 1, k), k in [1 .. n - 1])]

respectively (=):

[image: floor(sum(binomial(n, k), k in [1 .. n])/2)]

respectively (=):

[image: (2^(n-1)) -1]

---

An `O(log(n))` algorithm:

```
public class Test {


    public static long countSuperClever(int n) {
        return pow(2L, (long) n - 1) - 1L;
    }

    // best thx to https://codingforspeed.com/using-faster-integer-power-in-java/
    private static long pow(long a, long b) {
        long re = 1L;
        while (b > 0) {
            if ((b & 1) == 1) {
                re *= a;
            }
            b >>= 1;
            a *= a;
        }
        return re;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 3; i < 12; i++) {
            System.out.println(countSuperClever(i));
        }
    }

}
```

---

See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1338830/20447

Comment: Given an array A of N elements. The task is to count all the subsets whose sum is even.

Comment: ..exactly as i understood (by now), the answer is correct, count is =  `2^(n-1) - 1`

Comment: if((i&(1<<j))>0) :after generating the subset how should i check for the even sum.

Comment: ..when a number is even, you can check with `if( number % 2 == 0)` ...good luck!

Comment: but the subset elements need to be added to check for even

Comment: ...do it on paper (for n=3, 4... maybe 5)...think a little & i hope you will accept & understand the answer someday.